# 0.000226*1000 not give 0.226 but 0.22599999999999998

Tags: python

Why isn't the result of the following code 0.226?

```
In[6]: 0.000226*1000
Out[6]: 0.22599999999999998
```

I use python 3.6.

Comment: floating point maths, it's broken folks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html